# Система аутентификации как в Whatsapp/Viber в iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, swift

Должен создать программу (не чат), где регистрация пользователя будет проходит по номеру телефона как в Whatsapp и в других подобных программах. Как лучше всего это реализовать, чтобы после регистрации я мог бы видеть всех зареганых пользователей, но только из списка своих контактов. Есть какой-нибудь фреймворк или тутор где это описывает?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Средствами только iOS - никак. Обычно это делается сервером на основе данных, которые заливает клиент. На сервер отправляется телефонная книжка, сервер в свою очередь сохраняет это в свою базу и находит кого с кем связать. Социальный граф и всё такое.

**Обновление**

Разумеется. Чуда не произойдёт, чтобы знать кто уже зарегистрировался - надо иметь однозначную связь между номерами. Одностороннюю или двустороннюю. И связь эта должна трекаться на сервере, локально на аппарате такого не сделать в принципе.

Comment: т.е. при запросе на разрешение использование контактов, я должен все контакты сохранить в базе, а потом уже в зависимости кто будет регистрироваться, показывать только их в списке зареганых, я правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве готового стороннего решения можете попробовать [Digits](https://dev.twitter.com/digits/overview) от Twitter.

Comment: да, его хвалят. но мне не нравится, что все контакты будут храниться у него на сервере и у него всего стоит реклама наподобии Made by Twitter внизу формы, которую он генерит